# Error starting apache from terminal after removing MAMP

Tags: apache, macos, terminal, mamp

I removed MAMP recently.

When I try to start apache from Terminal using:

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

I am getting the message

```
Warning: DocumentRoot [usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, make sure you're actually trying to execute the proper version of apachectl by issuing the following command:

```
which apachectl
```

(You don't want to see any MAMP references there).

Next, find your virtual hosts config (which is likely here if your MAMP references are gone)

```
/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Make sure your virtual host definitions are good.  (Sounds like you're referencing a bad one).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Users/yourusername/Sites/mysite"
    ServerName mysite.local
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/mysite-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/mysite-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

(If you're using a custom server name other than 'localhost' like I've defined above, just be sure your /etc/hosts file is up to date with that entry like this:

```
127.0.0.1          mysite.local
```

Don't forget to restart apache!

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: This seems so obvious now that I read this...but at the same time there is no way I would have figured out all of these steps on my own...THANKS!

Comment: Missing it on configuring apache on mac for the first time.But thank God worked like a charm in the end!!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to go to apache config file (something like `etc/apache2/apache2.conf`) and set it an existing document root directory. That is usually done with `DocumentRoot` directive in this file, or one of the included virtual host config definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you comment out all the lines inside the /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file otherwise you will get the errors.