# Fresh lithium framework installation returns error 403

Tags: php, lithium

I read the docs and installed lithium exactly like they have explained but I keep on getting a 403 forbidden error. I am new to apache and php and I have been spending two full days trying to make lithium work. I am running apache 2.0 on osx lion and here is what I did:

1- I created a new directory called my_app in `localhost/~marwan/`

2- I extracted the sample lithium app in to that directory.

3- I downloaded the lithium framework and extracted it into `/libraries/lithium/`

When I access `http://localhost/~marwan/my_app/` I get the following 403 error:

> You don't have permission to access /~marwan/mj/ on this server.

I have researched and added *Options +FollowSymLinks* to the .htaccess file and the error changed to:

> You don't have permission to access
>   /Users/marwan/Sites/my_app/app/webroot/webroot/ on this server.

I have tried to add *Options +FollowSymLinks* to every .htaccess file but nothing changed.

I dont know if this is relevant: websites on localhost/~marwan/ work but localhost also shows a 403 error. I tried to fiddle with different permissions posted in previous answers but with no luck.

Thank you for your help.

httpd.conf file is here http://pastebin.com/jLwHPbuq

Edit:
httpd-userdir.conf is here http://pastebin.com/ZXi51pn7
httpd-vhosts.conf is here http://pastebin.com/3xqRmrzL

Update

The lithium project works when I remove the .htaccess from the main folder but it doesnt work properly because rewriting doesnt work. Here is the .htacces in the project root http://pastebin.com/vt0fVyyL

Comment: Please include your web server configuration

Comment: Can you please explain how would I do that? I am new to apache Should I attach the httpd.conf file?

Comment: Right, that's what I was talking about. And also include "default" file from "sites-enabled" if there is such file.

Comment: I have included the configuration file. I dont have a default file.

Comment: Good, now also please include these 2 files:
/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: I have included the two files. Thanks for pointing them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the error log after restarting apache and found DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist so I fixed it by using this answer stackoverflow.com/questions/6671042/… and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

The path you provide in the error message `/~marwan/mj/` and the path you provide that you are trying to reach `http://localhost/~marwan/my_app/` do not match. According to the error the web server says you are trying to access a directory called `mj` while your url does not include `mj` so unless you are doing some URL rewriting this looks like an issue.

Also, just to be clear, when you say you installed the library in `/libraries/litium` you mean relative to the web root path, correct?

---

OK, looking at your conf files you can serve files out of `/Library/WebServer/Documents` or out of `~/Sites` (that tilde represents your user directory so it is the same path as `/Users/marwan/Sites`)

Do this...

1. In `/Library/WebServer/Documents` place a file called `index.html` and have it output some text.
2. Make sure there are no .htaccess files in `/Library/WebServer/Documents`.
3. Make sure you have not modified your httpd.conf file in any way from its default settings.
4. Do you see the correct behavior for your index.html (you should)? If not, what happens?

Comment: Check the httpd-userdir.conf as well. He have access to his home directory.

Comment: I changed the path of the webroot in the httpd.conf to /Users/marwan/Sites and I added an index.html file to sites but locoalhost/index.html showed access forbidden (localhost/~marwan/sites/index.html still works). The lithium project works when I remove the .htaccess from the main folder but it doesnt work properly because rewriting doesnt work. Here is the .htacces in the project root http://pastebin.com/vt0fVyyL

Comment: You should not have changed that. Change the webroot path back to what it was `/Library/WebServer/Documents`... you already have it pointing to the correct places (reread my comment... 3rd section of text). Then  do what I suggest in my comment where I write: "Do this..."

Comment: I changed back httpd.conf to default but it didnt work. I looked at the error log after restarting apache and found DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist so I fixed it by using this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671042/error-starting-apache-from-terminal-using-leopard-after-removing-mamp and now it works. Your answer helped me understand a lot about apache. Thank you for your help.